# Multiple Timezoning in Laravel/Carbon

Tags: php, datetime, laravel, php-carbon

I was wondering if this was possible, so let's say I have a model like so:

```
MyModel
   SomeDate - Carbon
```

Now, I also have a timezone for the current user like so:

```
User
   MyTimezone
```

the timezones stored in the database are always stored in UTC format (to ensure everything is consistent), and the outputted dates should always be formatted to a specific Timezone (but timezone differs per user), for example America/Chicago for User1 and America/Denver for User2.

Is there a way to automatically format the timezones per Carbon instance to a given one before outputting, or will I have to loop through the collection and set each one accordingly?

Setting `app.timezone` doesn't work because it also causes Carbon instances to be saved to the database in the `app.timezone` timezone, whereas all dates in the database should be in UTC, therefore I lose consistency.

I currently have `app.timezone` set to UTC in the App config but I'm also forced to convert all Carbon instances to the correct timezone before outputting. Is there a better way, maybe by trapping execution before Carbon gets turned into a string and doing it there?

EDIT:

Things i've tried:

Override setAttribute & getAttribute:

```
public function setAttribute($property, $value) {
    if ($value instanceof Carbon) {
        $value->timezone = 'UTC';
    }

    parent::setAttribute($property, $value);
}

public function getAttribute($key) {
    $stuff = parent::getAttribute($key);

    if ($stuff instanceof Carbon) {
        $stuff->timezone = Helper::fetchUserTimezone();
    }

    return $stuff;
}
```

overriding asDateTime:

```
protected function asDateTime($value)
{
    // If this value is an integer, we will assume it is a UNIX timestamp's value
    // and format a Carbon object from this timestamp. This allows flexibility
    // when defining your date fields as they might be UNIX timestamps here.
    $timezone = Helper::fetchUserTimezone();

    if (is_numeric($value))
    {
        return Carbon::createFromTimestamp($value, $timezone);
    }

    // If the value is in simply year, month, day format, we will instantiate the
    // Carbon instances from that format. Again, this provides for simple date
    // fields on the database, while still supporting Carbonized conversion.
    elseif (preg_match('/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/', $value))
    {
        return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value, $timezone)->startOfDay();
    }

    // Finally, we will just assume this date is in the format used by default on
    // the database connection and use that format to create the Carbon object
    // that is returned back out to the developers after we convert it here.
    elseif ( ! $value instanceof DateTime)
    {
        $format = $this->getDateFormat();

        return Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $value, $timezone);
    }

    return Carbon::instance($value);
}
```

Comment: Just an idea but pass the Time data to JS and have the JS do the calculation for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you are trying to achieve is to convert timezone from A format to B format and send it to the user, where A format is stored in database and B format is converted to after retrieving records from database.

Here is a neat way to do that.

In the models such as `User` and `MyModel` where conversion is needed, add a function in model:

```
public function getConversionAttribute()
{
    $conversion = Convert($this->SomeDate);
    //Convert is the customized function to convert data format
    //SomeDate is the original column name of dates stored in your database
    return $conversion;
}
```

Now if you query User model or MyModel using `$user = User::find(1)`, you can now get the converted date by accessing the conversion attribute using `$user->conversion`.

Cheers!

However, attribute added this way will not included in converted array. You need to add another function in your model.

```
public function toArray()
{
    $array = parent::toArray();
    //if you want to override the original attribute
    $array['SomeDate'] = $this->conversion;
    //if you want to keep both the original format and the current format
    //use this: $array['Conversion'] = $this->conversion;
    return $array;
}
```

General Version:

```
public function toArray() {
    $array = parent::toArray();
    //if you want to override the original attribute
    $dates = $this->getDates();

    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        $local = $this->{$date}->copy();
        $local->timezone = ...
        $array[$date] = (string)$local;
    }
    //if you want to keep both the original format and the current format
    //use this: $array['Conversion'] = $this->conversion;
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is if I call `->toArray()` on the model, the value I want, eg `start_time` is still in the database timezone.

Comment: Try this: public function getConversionAttribute()
{
    $this->SomeDate = Convert($this->SomeDate);
    //Convert is the customized function to convert data format
    //SomeDate is the original column name of dates stored in your database
    return $this->SomeDate;
}

Comment: It should alter original format as you wish. As long as you do not save it in the database using `$this->save()`, the database entries will not be affected.

Comment: The problem goes with toArray(). Attribute added this way will not be included in converted array. But you can access them using `$this->conversion`

Comment: I need a way to output them by just using toArray(), as that is what all my code uses to convert objects to JSON format.

Comment: getConversionAttribute() as the name suggests, should add the attribute name 'conversion' in between get and attribute. You miss that in your implementation.

Comment: Hey, please see my edited answer. it should work now as you wish.

Comment: Cool, I just made a much more generalized version of your function, I'll accept yours now and I'll also add the generalized version.

Answer (score 5):

Running into the same issue for my application where remote websites would store dates in UTC and I'd have to show the actual dates based on the logged in user, I came up with overriding the Laravel Eloquent Model.

Just extend the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, like so:

```
<?php namespace Vendor\Package;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as EloquentModel;

class Model extends EloquentModel
{

    /**
    * Return a timestamp as a localized DateTime object.
    *
    * @param  mixed  $value
    * @return \Carbon\Carbon
    */
    protected function asDateTime($value)
    {
        $carbon = parent::asDateTime($value);
        // only make localized if timezone is known
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->timezone)
        {
            $timezone = new DateTimeZone(Auth::user()->timezone);
            // mutates the carbon object immediately
            $carbon->setTimezone($timezone);
        }

        return $carbon;
    }
    /**
    * Convert a localized DateTime to a normalized storable string.
    *
    * @param  \DateTime|int  $value
    * @return string
    */
    public function fromDateTime($value)
    {
        $save = parent::fromDateTime($value);

        // only make localized if timezone is known
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->timezone)
        {
            // the format the value is saved to
            $format = $this->getDateFormat();

            // user timezone
            $timezone = new DateTimeZone(Auth::user()->timezone);

            $carbon = Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $value, $timezone);
            // mutates the carbon object immediately
            $carbon->setTimezone(Config::get('app.timezone'));

            // now save to format
            $save = $carbon->format($format);
        }

        return $save;
    }
}
```

Perhaps this is useful for others stumbling upon this question.

As a reference

- laravel 5 (2015-03-18): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model:2809-2889
- laravel 4.2 (2015-03-18): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model:2583-2662